# How to pipe to stdin of os.execv'd process in Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to write something to the stdin of a process *replacing* my current Python process. Is there an easy way to do this? I was thinking along the lines of

```
import sys, os

r, w = os.pipe()
os.write(w, 'yo')
os.dup2(r, sys.stdin.fileno())
os.execvp('cat', [''])
```

but when I execute this in OS X, cat hangs, though 'yo' does get displayed. Why?

Comment: Code like this is dangerous—if you write more than one pipe buffer's worth of data to the pipe (whose size varies with OS etc.), then you're going to deadlock your process because there's no reader to drain the pipe yet.

Comment: Then how can I go about doing what I want in a safe way -- without writing a temporary file?

Comment: You `os.fork()` the process before `execvp()`-ing the child process; the parent then writes to the pipe while the child reads from it.  The parent must also `close()` the read end of the pipe after `fork()`, and the child must `dup2()` the read end onto `stdin` and then close both of the original pipe handles before `execvp()`.  It's pretty standard Unix pipe stuff.

Comment: Adam, if you still want to, write your comment as an answer and I'll select it. Learned from what you wrote and my own mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `os.fork()` the process before `execvp()`-ing the child process; the parent then writes to the pipe while the child reads from it.  The parent must also `close()` the read end of the pipe after `fork()`, and the child must `dup2()` the read end onto `stdin` and then close both of the original pipe handles before `execvp()`.  It's pretty standard Unix pipe stuff.

For example:

```
r, w = os.pipe()
if os.fork() == 0:
    # Child process
    os.dup2(r, sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.close(r)
    os.close(w)
    os.execvp(...)
else:
    # Parent process
    os.close(r)
    os.write(w, 'yo')
    ...
    os.close(w)  # When done writing
    os.wait()
```